# Grouping MySQL results buy times

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having trouble getting my SQL results to do what I need them to. I've been reading for awhile and I'm still having a little snag. I have a database with times in it. What I'm trying to do is return the amount of calls that fall within each hour. I'm trying to avoid doing 24 different queries for each hour and was hoping the group function might be something I can work with. Is it possible to do one query on this table and be able to group them into one hour increments, or do I need to do individual queries for each hour. My end result will have the number of calls that happened in each of the 24 hours.

```
+----------+---------+
| calltime | time    |
+----------+---------+
| 160523   |  4:05pm |
| 150259   |  3:02pm |
| 025942   |  2:59am |
| 024729   |  2:47am |
| 072419   |  7:24am |
| 142450   |  2:24pm |
| 201937   |  8:19pm |
| 190428   |  7:04pm |
+----------+---------+
```

Is this possible?

Answer:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY HOUR(calltime)
```

And then looping through results.

Comment: COUNT(*) and GROUP BY HOUR(time) should work... On a sidenote, your design is no good - use date instead of just time and why are the times in different formats? It's inconvenient and not useful at all.

Comment: Select * FROM table GROUP BY calltime. But this doesn't break anything down by the hour, which is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: It is part of a larger database with dates etc. I'm just need to display the calls based on time.

Comment: Put sample data and attempted query on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I got the COUNT(*) and GROUP BY HOUR(time) working, the only thing this is that it is only giving me 12 results instead on the full 24.

Comment: It is because, you've been using the 12-hour clock, use 24-hour clock time in the time field & then do group by; you'll get your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT HOUR(STR_TO_DATE( time, '%l:%i:%S %p' )), COUNT(calltime) FROM table GROUP BY HOUR(STR_TO_DATE( time, '%l:%i:%S %p' ));
```

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).